# Difference between ssl/https and plain https in nmap output

Tags: nmap

I'm trying to analyze the behavior of an IP that works as free WiFi access point. `nmap` with parameter (`-sV`) reports the following for two different measurements:

```
PORT STATE SERVICE VERSION 443/tcp open ssl/https?
PORT STATE SERVICE VERSION 443/tcp open https?
```

Why does one show up as `ssl/https`? while the other is just `https`?

Comment: is this reproducable? could you provide us the data traffic generated by nmap, i.e. the file `/tmp/for_ul_se.pcap` generated by `tcpdump -i <your_wlan_interface_name> -s0 -w/tmp/for_ul_se.pcap port 443`?

Answer (score 1):

In looking through the online help for `nmap` I found the following description for services that are prefixed with `ssl/`.

*excerpt from - http://nmap.org/book/vscan-fileformat.html#vscan-db-ports*

> `<service>`
>
> This is simply the service name that the pattern matches. Examples
> would be ssh, smtp, http, or snmp. As a special case, you can prefix
> the service name with ssl/, as in ssl/vmware-auth. In that case, the
> service would be stored as vmware-auth tunneled by SSL. This is useful
> for services which can be fully recognized without the overhead of
> making an SSL connection.

#### References

- [Testing for Weak SSL/TLS Ciphers/Protocols/Keys vulnerabilities](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Testing_for_Weak_SSL/TLS_Ciphers,_Insufficient_Transport_Layer_Protection_(OTG-CRYPST-001)#Testing_for_Weak_SSL.2FTLS_Ciphers.2FProtocols.2FKeys_vulnerabilities)

Comment: but it is due to a measurement of results with ssl and without ssl another? 
in detail that is? ... packet loss?

Comment: I suspect that one of the AP's is using an older set of SSL cipher suites, say SSLv2 vs. SSLv3 (TLSv1). You have to make use of additional switching as described in the reference url that I provided to confirm this though.

Comment: When doing what you told me, it gives me this result: 

PORT STATE SERVICE 
443/tcp open https

Comment: one last question @slm ... As I can describe in detail the different results specifically? In some cases, it may be due to packet loss when running nmap?